# What is the buffers column in the output from free?

Tags: linux, memory, cache

[These](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14102/real-memory-usage) [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33541/free-output-format) briefly list the format of the free command, noting that buffers is kernel memory that must be written out to disk and cache is file data that does not need to be written disk.

On my system, unlike most times I have run free, buffers occupies over 10% of RAM.  Usually, buffers are a small, almost token, value.

My question is, what exactly is in the area called buffers?  Can I look for it with `lsof`?  Does it consist of open file regions that have not been flushed?  Is it memory mapped file regions?  What is it?

The system runs well and little swap is used, so performance is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`free` pulls its data from `/proc/meminfo`

```
slkwr133701:/usr/src/linux # free

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       2053456     434572    1618884          0      77888     201820

slkwr133701:/usr/src/linux # cat /proc/meminfo

MemTotal:        2053456 kB
MemFree:         1618736 kB
Buffers:           77928 kB
....
```

This refers to memory used for temporary block I/O storage.
The kernel has to assign and free the same size units constantly like block I/O transfers, network packets, and socket buffers

You can get a better look at caches and buffer allocations by running `slabtop`

In response to your usage question: The system will typically allocate more blocks than it needs but as the "memory pressure" increases these additional blocks will be released.

Comment: Specifically, "buffers" in `free` additionally includes SReclaimable (reclaimable slabs). `slabtop` won't show direct stats about page cache, just these slabs that are aggregated under "buffers" in `free`. AFAICT, `slabtop` / slabinfo doesn't give stats on slabs as reclaimable or not. But usually that's ok, and if there is some suspicious slab I guess you can look it up by name. https://www.logicmonitor.com/blog/right-way-to-monitor-linux-memory-again/

Answer (score 2):

"buffers" are reclaimable under memory pressure.  So it is similar to the page cache ("cache" column); not a big cause for concern.  The "buffers" value can be small or large, it depends what your system is doing :-).  We can find several types of cache counted here.

The buffer cache is literally the page cache for the block device.  Linux just reports these separately.[*]  You could notice "buffers" usage while programs read/write the block device node, e.g. `dd status=progress if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null`.  Apparently people also notice it when running a DVD player program.

For proof, see: [30% of RAM is "buffers". What is it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440558/30-of-ram-is-buffers-what-is-it/440563#440563)

If you have not been accessing the block device node, your "buffers" are probably all filesystem *metadata*.  Filesystems use the buffer cache internally as a convenience.  They make sure it never duplicates the file *data* - file contents - which is stored in the main page cache.  Exactly what the filesystem uses the buffer cache for - if anything - varies depending on the filesystem.

On a machine with a small amount of physical RAM, I noticed "buffers" can look high, when I have ext3/ext4 filesystems.  This was because writes to the journal go through the buffer cache.  (See link above).  ext3/4 filesystems also store directory contents in the buffer cache.

Secondly, "buffers" shown by the `free` command also include SReclaimable, meaning reclaimable slabs.  (Demonstrated here: [The Right Way to Monitor Linux Memory, Again](https://www.logicmonitor.com/blog/right-way-to-monitor-linux-memory-again/)).

Slab memory is *not* part of the page/buffer cache.  However it is convenient to count them together.  They are both reclaimable, and the main (only?) use of reclaimable slabs is for filesystem caching.  For example file metadata (inodes) and path lookups (dentry's) are cached in reclaimable slabs.  "[Reclaimable slab memory [can] take up a large fraction of system memory on mostly idle systems with lots of files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499649/is-cached-memory-de-facto-free/499651#499651)."

You can see the raw `Buffers` and `SReclaimable` values in `cat /proc/meminfo`.  You can also run `slabtop` to see the list of slabs.  AFAICT, `slabtop` doesn't give stats on slabs as reclaimable or not.  But you can usually guess, and if there is some suspicious slab I guess you can look it up by name.

---

[*] For the purposes of this answer, "buffer cache" is the cache counted by `Buffers` in `/proc/meminfo`.  However other sources may refer to the entire page cache as a unified buffer cache.  If you want the historical explanation, see the first link.

Also Linux developers may have used "buffer cache" to mean different things, when they were squabbling about filesystem implementations.

Answer (score 0):

> Secondly, "buffers" shown by the free command also include SReclaimable

According to man page of free command (version 3.3.15):
"cache  Memory  used by the page cache and slabs (Cached and SReclaimable in /proc/meminfo)"

So it is the cache that includes SReclaimable, not the buffers.