# Is "Cached" memory de-facto free?

Tags: linux, memory, cache, meminfo

When running `cat /proc/meminfo`, you get these 3 values at the top:

```
MemTotal:        6291456 kB
MemFree:         4038976 kB
Cached:          1477948 kB
```

As far as I know, the "Cached" value is disk caches made by the Linux system that will be freed immediately if any application needs more RAM, thus Linux will never run out of memory until both MemFree and Cached are at zero.

Unfortunately, "MemAvailable" is not reported by /proc/meminfo, probably because it is running in a virtual server. (Kernel version is 4.4)

Thus for all practical purposes, the RAM available for applications is MemFree + Cached.

Is that view correct?

Comment: I don't want to gold-hammer this closed, but [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/261247/86440) is relevant if not a duplicate. I’m surprised you don’t have `MemAvailable`, it was added in 3.14.

Comment: The accepted answer from that question uses /proc/zoneinfo, which isn't available on my vserver as well

Comment: uname -a: Linux host 4.4.0-042stab134.8 #1 SMP Fri Dec 7 17:16:09 MSK 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I suspect this is an OpenVZ system with a kernel which is really based on 2.6.32, not 4.4.

Comment: I notice [2.6.32-042stab134.8 is one commonly used OpenVZ kernel](https://stats.openvz.org/kernel.php). To take an example completely at random. </snark>

Comment: @sourcejedi and it was compiled at exactly the same time as the 4.4 kernel!

Comment: yeah, I'm going to roll back that title edit, since it seems to make this a different question (the original didn't even mention `MemAvailable`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That view can be very misleading in a number of real-world cases.

The kernel now provides an estimate for available memory, in the `MemAvailable` field.  This value is significantly different from `MemFree + Cached`.

> [/proc/meminfo: provide estimated available memory](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/34e431b0ae39) [kernel change description, 2014]
>
> **Many load balancing and workload placing programs check /proc/meminfo
>   to estimate how much free memory is available. They generally do this
>   by adding up "free" and "cached", which was fine ten years ago, but is
>   pretty much guaranteed to be wrong today.**
>
> It is wrong because Cached
>   includes memory that is not freeable as page cache, for example shared
>   memory segments, tmpfs, and ramfs, and it does not include reclaimable
>   slab memory, which can take up a large fraction of system memory on
>   mostly idle systems with lots of files.
>
> Currently, the amount of
>   memory that is available for a new workload, without pushing the
>   system into swap, can be estimated from MemFree, Active(file),
>   Inactive(file), and SReclaimable, as well as the "low" watermarks from
>   /proc/zoneinfo. However, this may change in the future, and user space
>   really should not be expected to know kernel internals to come up with
>   an estimate for the amount of free memory. It is more convenient to
>   provide such an estimate in /proc/meminfo. If things change in the
>   future, we only have to change it in one place.
>   
> ...
>
> Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt:
>   
> ...
>   MemAvailable: An estimate of how much memory is available for
>   starting new
>                 applications, without swapping. Calculated from MemFree,
>                 SReclaimable, the size of the file LRU lists, and the low
>                 watermarks in each zone.
>                 The estimate takes into account that the system needs some
>                 page cache to function well, and that not all reclaimable
>                 slab will be reclaimable, due to items being in use. The
>                 impact of those factors will vary from system to system.

### 1. MemAvailable details

As it says above, tmpfs and other `Shmem` memory cannot be freed, only moved to swap.  `Cached` in `/proc/meminfo` can be very misleading, due to including this swappable `Shmem` memory.  If you have too many files in a tmpfs, it could be occupying a lot of your memory :-).  `Shmem` can also include some [graphics memory allocations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482795/can-i-see-the-amount-of-memory-which-is-allocated-as-gem-buffers), which could be very large.

`MemAvailable` deliberately does not include swappable memory.  Swapping too much can cause long delays.  You might even have chosen to run without swap space, or allowed only a relatively limited amount.

I had to double-check how `MemAvailable` works.  At first glance, the code did not seem to mention this distinction.

```
/*
 * Not all the page cache can be freed, otherwise the system will
 * start swapping. Assume at least half of the page cache, or the
 * low watermark worth of cache, needs to stay.
 */
pagecache = pages[LRU_ACTIVE_FILE] + pages[LRU_INACTIVE_FILE];
pagecache -= min(pagecache / 2, wmark_low);
available += pagecache;
```

However, I found it correctly treats `Shmem` as "used" memory.  I created several 1GB files in a tmpfs.  Each 1GB increase in `Shmem` reduced `MemAvailable` by 1GB.  So the size of the "file LRU lists" does not include shared memory or any other swappable memory.  (I noticed these same page counts are also used [in the code that calculates the "dirty limit"](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/a1c3bfb2f67e)).

This `MemAvailable` calculation also assumes that you want to keep at least enough file cache to equal the kernel's "low watermark".  Or half of the current cache - whichever is smaller.  (It makes the same assumption for reclaimable slabs as well).  The kernel's "low watermark" can be tuned, but it is usually [around 2% of system RAM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/512378/how-large-are-the-watermark-memory-reservations-on-my-system).  So if you only want a rough estimate, you can ignore this part :-).

When you are running `firefox` with around 100MB of program code mapped in the page cache, you generally want to keep that 100MB in RAM :-).  Otherwise, at best you will suffer delays, at worst the system will spend all its time [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)) between different applications.  So `MemAvailable` is allowing a small percentage of RAM for this.  It might not allow enough, or it might be over-generous.  "The impact of those factors will vary from system to system".

For many PC workloads, the point about "lots of files" might not be relevant.  Even so, I currently have 500MB reclaimable slab memory on my laptop (out of 8GB of RAM).  This is due to `ext4_inode_cache` (over 300K objects).  It happened because I recently had to scan the whole filesystem, to find what was using my disk space :-).  I used the command `df -x / | sort -n`, but e.g. Gnome Disk Usage Analyzer would do the same thing.

### 2. [edit] Memory in control groups

So-called "Linux containers" are built up from `namespaces`, `cgroups`, and various other features according to taste :-).  They may provide a convincing enough environment to run something almost like a full Linux system.  Hosting services can build containers like this and sell them as "virtual servers" :-).

**Hosting servers may also build "virtual servers" using features which are not in mainline Linux.  [OpenVZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openvz) containers pre-date mainline cgroups by two years, and may use "beancounters" to limit memory.  So you cannot understand exactly how those memory limits work if you only read documents or ask questions about the mainline Linux kernel.  [`cat /proc/user_beancounters`](https://wiki.openvz.org/Proc/user_beancounters) shows current usage and limits.  [`vzubc`](https://openvz.livejournal.com/42146.html) presents it in a slightly more friendly format.  The [main page on beancounters](https://wiki.openvz.org/UBC) documents the row names.**

Control groups include the ability to set memory limits on the processes inside them.  If you run your application inside such a cgroup, then not all of the system memory will be available to the application :-).  So, how can we see the available memory in this case?

The interface for this differs in a number of ways, depending if you use [cgroup-v1](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt) or [cgroup-v2](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v2.txt).

My laptop install uses cgroup-v1.  I can run `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat`.  The file shows various fields including `total_rss`, `total_cache`, `total_shmem`.  shmem, including tmpfs, counts towards the memory limits.  I guess you can look at `total_rss` as an inverse equivalent of `MemFree`.  And there is also the file `memory.kmem.usage_in_bytes`, representing kernel memory including slabs.  (I assume `memory.kmem.` also includes `memory.kmem.tcp.` and any future extensions, although this is not documented explicitly).  There are not separate counters to view reclaimable slab memory.  The document for cgroup-v1 says hitting the memory limits does *not* trigger reclaim of any slab memory.  (The document also has a disclaimer that it is "hopelessly outdated", and that you should check the current source code).

cgroup-v2 is different.  I think the root (top-level) cgroup doesn't support memory accounting.  cgroup-v2 still has a `memory.stat` file.  All the fields sum over child cgroups, so you don't need to look for `total_...` fields.  There is a `file` field, which means the same thing `cache` did.  Annoyingly I don't see an overall field like `rss` inside `memory.stat`; I guess you would have to add up individual fields.  There are separate stats for reclaimable and unreclaimable slab memory; I think a v2 cgroup is designed to reclaim slabs when it starts to run low on memory.

**Linux cgroups do not automatically virtualize `/proc/meminfo` (or any other file in `/proc`), so that would show the values for the entire machine.  This would confuse VPS customers.  However it is possible to use namespaces to replace `/proc/meminfo` with a file [faked up by the specific container software](http://download.parallels.com/doc/psbm/v5/rtm/Parallels_Server_Bare_Metal_Users_Guide/16667.htm).  How useful the fake values are, would depend on what that specific software does.**

`systemd` believes cgroup-v1 cannot be securely delegated e.g. to containers.  I looked inside a `systemd-nspawn` container on my cgroup-v1 system.  I can see the cgroup it has been placed inside, and the memory accounting on that.  On the other hand the contained `systemd` does not set up the usual per-service cgroups for resource accounting.  If memory accounting was not enabled inside this cgroup, I assume the container would not be able to enable it.

I assume if you're inside a cgroup-v2 container, it will look different to the root of a real cgroup-v2 system, and you will be able to see memory accounting for its top-level cgroup.  Or if the cgroup you can see does not have memory accounting enabled, hopefully you will be delegated permission so you can [enable memory accounting in `systemd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499496/29483) (or equivalent).

Comment: Official doc https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0-rc5/source/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt#L903

Comment: it clicky nao.  I use GitHub links because they show the first release containing the commit (similar to `git describe --contains`).  Found it linked as a TL;DR by an SU question, which turned out to be just quoting the section added to proc.txt.  But for this question, the commit description is just perfect IMO :-).

Comment: MemAvailable doesn't seem to be available on most virtual servers... what to do then?

Comment: @RolandSeuhs possibly learn "beancounters". See edits in bold. If you have a question about beancounters, I would appreciate it if you ask a new question.  We can always link to it from this one, but the details are probably not relevant to any readers who use a mainline linux kernel.

Answer (score 2):

With modern Linux kernels and `/proc/meminfo`, the `Cached` value includes all of `Shmem` which also includes all the `tmpfs` usage so it's definitely not de-facto free for the programs to use if needed. In my experience `Cached - Shmem` matches the actually freeable memory pretty well. Note that none of the `Shmem` can be freed without killing processes but it can be swapped if memory is getting low.

I'd recommend checking these values (my example output):

```
$ grep -E "^MemTotal|^Cached|^Committed_AS|^Shmem:|^MemAvailable|^MemFree" /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:       32570668 kB
MemFree:         8245572 kB
MemAvailable:    7817776 kB
Cached:         11553648 kB
Shmem:          10604700 kB
Committed_AS:   36945628 kB
```

Also note that my `MemAvailable` is less than `MemFree` because some of the memory is estimated fragmented and cannot be directly used with full performance.

Another estimate of your actually freeable `Cached` can be found like this:

```
$ sudo slabtop -sc -o | head | grep "Total Size"
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 548703.26K / 672516.95K (81.6%)
```

Note that in my case about 550 MB is in active use and if freed, would cause performance drop for the system.

**TL;DR:** Do not look at `Free` or `Cached` because those names are misleading for their real purpose, just look at `MemAvailable` which is the amount of RAM you can afford to spend more if needed.