# Critical Memory

Tags: linux, rhel, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [`free`: output format](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33541/free-output-format)

My Redhat server shows the following:

```
free -m 
============= 
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached 
Mem:          8113       8078        35          0        171       6491   
-/+ buffers/cache:       1415       6698   
Swap:         8189         59       8130
```

Is 35 mega of free memory considered critical on a production server ?

Comment: Nothing to be worried about - see http://serverfault.com/a/379392 for more details.

Comment: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: its used for a java application

Answer (score 2):

Ulrich gave you two links that go into detail, which are correct.

Here's the TL;DR version.

**Add `free` and `cache`. That's how much RAM is available to any application that wants to use it.** (In your case, about 6.5GB out of 8GB total).

If you want to know more more, read those links from Ulrich.

Answer (score 0):

How long is piece of string?

Whether it's bad depends what your server is doing. For a SMTP relay, a Java Application server or a MySQL DBMS server running exclusvely innoDB tables it's not a problem. For a lot of other applications, it will have a dire effect on performance. You didn't say what the box is used for.

Comment: usually half as long as I need, and almost as long as a piece of chalk.